# Retrieve the name of the person who has done an activity to a Word document to advise other users who have the document open

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want the name or account name of the person who is currently working on a document.

E.g.
I and other users have simultaneously opened a document to let **one of them do some activity**.
I want to send notification to all the users who have the document open **except the one who has done that activity**.

I tried `Application.UserName` but it is giving me my machine name, not the account name with which the Word application was opened.

Comment: Do you need a name of the user logged in Office or OS?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Yes Eugene, exactly

Answer (score 1):

This should return what you want:

```
Environ$("USERNAME")
```

The [Environ function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/environ-function) returns the value of system Environment variables, one of which is the name of the current user logged on to the system. You could also use this to get the hostname of the machine (COMPUTERNAME), or get other information about the system.

You can get a full list of environment variables which can be used with this function from the Windows command prompt:

```
SET
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P thanks for the feedback, I tried to make this a bit more clear!

Comment: Is not this going to show the poster his/her own name when he opens the document? How would this be preserved in the document?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon it will, and will also show any other user their own name. Perhaps I misunderstood the question. It seemed like the poster was asking how to get the username with VBA when the document was opened, and then send that out as a notification to other users. I took this as part 1 of a 2 part solution (get the name via VBA, which each user would run when they open the document). Part 2 would be sending this notification out, which could happen from the machine of each user which opened the document, not necessarily just the OP's machine.